# Создание коммита перед существующим коммитом в git

Tags: git

У меня есть ветка и в ней один коммит, и мне необходимо вернутся в исходное состояние ветки и создать коммит с предварительными изменениями, что бы в итоге было два коммита, первый - тот что нужно создать и второй - текущий. Пытался откатиться с помощью `git checkout HEAD^` но таким образом меня перебрасывает на предыдущий коммит в другой ветке.

Comment: сделайте коммит как обычно, а потом с помощью  rebase -i HEAD~2 сделайте интерактивный ребейз, где и поменяйте коммиты местами.

Answer (score 1):

1. С помощью команды `git log --graph --pretty=oneline --abbrev-commit` или любого графического клиента git посмотрите дерево.
2. Найдите хэш родительского коммита.
3. Создайте на нем новую ветку, и переключитесь на нее.
4. Внесите и закоммитьте ваши предварительные изменения.
5. При помощи rebase перенесите ваш один коммит в новую ветку.

Готово